# How to change the alpha of a tilemap if the player is in it in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection, tilemap, transparency

I'm working on a 2D game and would like to have it so when I'm entering a building, the roof fades away. This is my current attempt, I'd just like to know how to set the alpha of a tilemap through c#.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RoofTransparency : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }


    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        Debug.Log("Inside building");

        tilemap.color = color(0, 255, 0);
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        Debug.Log("Outside building");
    }
}
```

Comment: [Color Constructor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color-ctor.html) has a form that accepts four arguments, where the fourth argument is alpha.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for what you need. If you wanted to have it on like the grass layer but make your roof layer transparent just do this to the code.

```cs
public class RoofTransparency : MonoBehaviour
{
   
     Tilemap m_Renderer;
 
     // Start is called before the first frame update
     void Start()
     {
         //Grabs the Tilemap Component
         m_Renderer = GetComponentInParent<Tilemap>();
     }
 
     private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
     {
         Debug.Log("Player has entered the trigger");
 
         //Turns object invisible when the player enters its collider space
         if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
         {
             m_Renderer.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.0f);
         }
     }
 
     private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
     {
         Debug.Log("Player has exited the trigger");
 
         //Turns object visible when player enters its collider space
         if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
         {
             m_Renderer.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
         }
     }
}
```